# How can we get rid of the Sign-Up form?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, user-expectation

Edited:

For some, this question might be irrelevant since most of the major large internet enterprises are using the Sign-Up form, but let's forget about their reasoning for a second.

We often face the issue that a Sign-up form separates the inside world from the outside world of an application. Therefore, attracting a user to Sign-up relies a lot on the first impression - like the Homepage for instance.

This problem reminds me with the metaphor of "Judging a book based on its cover", I am trying to research different approaches that put this metaphor away from the way we design products.

I've seen many that try to embed the Sign-up, after committing the user to the product. MindMeister for instance, allows you to use the application without signing up, but once you want to save your work, you will have to sign up.

This is one approach, What are some other approaches - regardless of the pros and cons - that can solve this?

Not in a specific context, rather than the common applications, take any Wordpress site for instance, where we collect the common fields:

- Full Name
- Email
- Gender

PS: I'm not asking about the technologies, but rather than approaches.

Comment: We may need more context to answer. Someone may just answer "drop login" and it may work in some circumstances. Someone else may suggest to simply support Open ID (which will reroute to a login page...). Someone else may suggest to use AD authentication in Intranet...and so on...

Comment: We definitely need some context. Who is your user?

Comment: Yeah the question seems too general. Please specify for what kind of application you want to replace the sign up form?

Comment: I hope i clarified a bit more...

Comment: This is too much of a discussion topic rather than a specific situation that you need a solution to. All answers to this would be equally valid, therefore it doesn't really fit with the scope of this site. Please take the [tour] to get a bigger overview.

Comment: @JonW I missed that one, i thought discussions were allowed, should I delete the topic?

Answer (score 2):

From UX perspective, signup can be replaced with "Lets Interact". A storytellibg which keepa user involeved while going through the features and ask the details/user input as part of the interaction.

Showing the SignUp form directly repells users from website....this can be replaced with an animated interaction which lets user know about the site firstand then provide details as he moves through it.

Comment: True, This can humanize the Sign-Up process much more than "please fill up this document". Thanks